# Deploying software that interacts with USB peripherals

Tags: windows, usb, driver, libusbdotnet

I've been very new to driver development and recently read about communicating with USB peripherals using [LibUsbDotNet](http://libusbdotnet.sourceforge.net/V2/Index.html).

Currently I'm developing a small library for interacting with the OBD interface built into vehicles. The serial connection works great but since I've seen many USB connectors I wanted to let people use their USB connectors with this library.

The introduction page of [LibUsbDotNet](http://libusbdotnet.sourceforge.net/V2/Index.html) says:

> Before LibUsbDotNet can access a usb device on a Windows operating system the device must be installed with either WinUSB or libusb-win32 usb drivers. Optionally, libusb-win32 has the unique ability to operate as a filter service. When the filter service mode is enabled, libusb-win32 will allow access to every usb device on the system without the need for driver setup/installation packages.

Does that mean that I'll need to create own driver packages for **every single** USB to OBD connector and deploy it with the library? Is there really the need for a driver? I only want to read from the USB port and transfer data to it. So that the interface on the other end may receive my messages and respond to me - just as the COM port.

Comment: Well, libusb isn't used for USB-serial converters.  Those have virtual COMM port drivers, either vendor-provided or Microsoft's `usbcdc.sys` which loads for devices that conform to the USB standard Communication Device Class.

Comment: How'd I access this vendor provided driver? Is there a generic solution or does that depend on the vendor?

Comment: For USB-serial converters, you open the COM port by name or number.  (The Microsoft-provided `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` class only supports numbers, and has a number of other more serious problems, so I suggest you use the Win32 API for serial ports, either through p/invoke or a better wrapper library)

Comment: Now, it's not just a matter of talking to the device, but understanding the protocol it speaks.  I don't know whether OBD bridges have a standardized format the way, for example, GPS devices have NMEA.

Comment: Oh, that's not a problem at all. Communicating with a serial to usb adapter works fine (it is listed as actual COM port) but when communicating with a end to end usb cable (with no serial converter at all, just the obd connector at one side and the usb connector at the other side) I can't use the serial port class since in this case, nothing is mapped as COM port.

Comment: Not all USB-serial converters have a DB9 serial connector, some are integrated into the device (many many GPS units work this way).  But if you don't see a COM port after connection, even with the right drivers installed, then you're probably working with something other than USB-serial.  Once you go beyond the usual device classes (Communication Device class, Mass Storage class, etc) then it becomes increasingly likely to need special support for each individual device model.

Comment: The point of libusb is to provide a single driver for all USB devices, at the common level of abstraction (basically, USB descriptors and end-points).  You still need an install package with each individual VID&PID combination listed, however, in order to be able to use libusb.  And you need model-specific detail about the exact message format the device expects on its endpoints.